# Compare all 70 columns from two tables in same database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with 70 columns each and they have same columns names in each table. I want to compare the data of every column and the output is number of rows which are different of every column. So far I am successful in comparing the data but I have to manually replace the column names in query instead I would like the query to pick all the columns data from both the tables and compare them and give output. Below is the query and sample output.

```
    select 
  NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF.StudentsClass4_15,NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF_old.StudentsClass4_15
from NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF
join NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF_old ON NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF.FormID=NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF_old.FormID
where NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF.StudentsClass4_15<>NEEF_Entry.dbo.tbl_TOF_old.StudentsClass4_15
```

output is:
[image]
The output shows how many rows in each column are different in this case 184.
Sorry about bad formatting.

Comment: Could you please supply some sample data contained in the two tables? And possibly add the DDL of the tables?

Comment: Your query does not show the "number of rows", but each row for which there is a different value in the old table, together with all rows from the old table where the value for that column differs.  I wonder what use your query could have.  Can you explain what it is that you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for messy, one-off dynamic SQL. You will likely want to prettify the text output and inspect the results (keeping an eye out for null comparisons), but hopefully this helps get you started.

```
declare @my_big_query nvarchar(max) = 'select a.MyPrimaryKeyColumn';
declare @my_big_sum   nvarchar(max) = 'select ';

select @my_big_query += 
    convert(nvarchar(max),',iif(a.'+quotename(a.name)+'=b.'+quotename(b.name)+',0,1) as '+quotename(a.name+'_IsNotEqual'))
from sys.columns a
join sys.columns b on a.name = b.name
where a.object_id = object_id('dbo.tbl_TOF')
    and b.object_id = object_id('dbo.tbl_TOF_old');

select @my_big_sum += 
    'a.'+quotename(a.name+'_IsNotEqual')+'+'
from sys.columns a
where a.object_id = object_id('dbo.tbl_TOF')

select @my_big_query += convert(nvarchar(max),'
into #cached_results
from dbo.tbl_TOF a
join dbo.tbl_TOF_old b on a.MyPrimaryKeyColumn = b.MyPrimaryKeyColumn;')
    ,@my_big_sum += 'a.MyPrimaryKeyColumn from #cached_results a;'


print 'drop table if exists #cached_results;'
print @my_big_query
print @my_big_sum
```